# CSS Mask repeat only on time in X and Y axis

Tags: css, css-mask

I want to use a mask in CSS to mask an element.
But it repeats in entire of my element.
I want only one mask in a specific position.
This what I have right now:
[image]

But I want something like this:
[image]

For the record, I know there is a `mask-repeat` property in CSS. But it only works with `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` values.
So, how can I have only one mask in my element?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: *But it only works with repeat-x and repeat-y values* --> no, you can specify `no-repeat`